# How to convert a string to a Javascript object with a property and a function reference?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I would like to produce a Javascript object which contains a property (onClick example) of type function (myClickHandler example) like this:

```
var options = {onClick: this.myClickHandler};
```

I want the object above to be created from a string because the options object can be different every time the app runs and I want it to be evaluated during runtime. (`myClickHandler` is an existing function). I want the options object created from    a string because onClick property can be something else and its function can be something else also. These are determined from the string which is dynamic.

Looking for something like this:

```
var optionsString = "{onClick: this.myClickHandler}";  
var options = JSON.parse(optionsString); //won't work. For illustration only.
```

This won't work naturally. Ideally, I want to convert the string in one go but I might have to parse it but optionString can contain one or more properties.

Comment: If it's a function contained in a string, `var options = {onClick: new Function(this.myClickHandler)};` ? But do try to avoid `new Function` and `eval`..

Comment: The right side of the equation is a string. There are no strings in your comment and I don't see how it would work.

Comment: Equation, what do you mean? Is that something with a special meaning in Typescript? (Sorry, I don't know Typescript) I'm not sure what you're asking, you say `this.myClickHandler` is a string, do you want the string as-is, or a function? (if function, then use `new Function`)

Comment: The whole thing to the right of the equal sign is a string. The '{onClick: this.myClickHandler}' part. The value is determined during runtime. Next time it runs, options might = {onClick: this.someOtherMethod, draw:false}.

Comment: How is this question related to `angularjs`? Are you going to pass this function to some component/directive?

Comment: Thinking about this in angular way -- you should use function that return object.
    var str = 'function() { var t = {}; return t;}' And then all comes to question what params this function should have, e.g. you want inject $scope or service, or what? Though it all seems not good and probably if you share initial problem - there is much easier solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `eval` as :

```
var myClickHandler = function(){ alert('i am evil'); };
var options = JSON.parse('{ "onClick": "this.myClickHandler" }');
```

// calling handler now

```
eval(options.onClick)();
```

Comment: This is not going to work in my case. The options object is used by a third party library. I can't stick eval and a function call to it.

Comment: you can expose function as : var click =  eval(options.onClick); and it can be used as click();

Comment: No. Options has to be an object exactly the way I mentioned. Now you introduced a new variable.

Answer (score 0):

You need some context where the function is bound to, so that you can access the function by key (which can be a string).

```js
let context = {};

context.myclickhandler = () => {
 console.log("### It clix ####")
}

let nameOfFunction = "myclickhandler"
let obj = {"onClick" : context[nameOfFunction]};
obj["onClick"]();
```

In the example the context is just an object , but it could also be the windows object or a instance  of a constructor function.